# Django forms.FileField validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am using a filefield and a text field in my form

```
class SolutionForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
    file  = forms.FileField(required=False)
```

I have also defined a clean method:

```
def clean(self,*args, **kwargs):
    if (not self.data['file'] or self.data['text']):
         raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter your code in text box or upload an arrpopriate file.')
return self.data['text']
```

but when submitting the form i get the following errors:

```
"Key 'file' not found in <QueryDict: {u'text': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'c52ea10c16620d3ebf0a20f015a3711d'], u'version': [u'C 1.1.1']}>"
```

How do I reference file field ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Pankaj.

Comment: Does https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/ help?

Comment: +1 lazy1, just check request.FILES['file']

Comment: I can't do that in the clean method(), there is no request variable there. Is there some way to verify in the clean method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# inside SolutionForm class
def clean(self):
    if not (self.cleaned_data['file'] or self.cleaned_data['text']):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter your code in text box or upload an appropriate file.')
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: My bad. I was doing the validation in "clean_text" instead of the main "clean" method. Correcting that did the trick