# Django validate FileField with clean()

Tags: django, forms, filefield

I have a Form that includes a FileField and a CharField. Both work as expected.

Neither field is required by itself, but one of them has to be given. So I want to add a validation that fails if both are empty.

in `forms.py`:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    mytext = forms.CharField(
        label = "Enter text",
        required=False
        )
    myfile = forms.FileField(
        label = "Or upload file",
        required=False
        )

    def clean(self):
        super(MyForm, self).clean()

        mytext_value = self.cleaned_data.get("mytext")
        myfile_value = self.cleaned_data.get("myfile")  # this remains empty, even after selecting a file! :-(

        if not mytext_value and not myfile_value:
            self.add_error("mytext", "Either text or file must be given!")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

This validation fails even if a file has been uploaded! (It does not fail if the text field has been used.)

If I disable the validation, the form works fine within the app. In `views.py`, I can get the uploaded file from the request (`myfile_value = request.FILES.get("myfile")`) and work with it.

But how do I get the content of the file during the `clean()` call, where I do not have a request, yet?

`self.files` gives me an empty MultiValueDict, `self.data` doesn't contain the key `myfile` at all, and in `self.cleaned_data`, `myfile` is `None`.

**How can I check during form validation whether a FileField has been filled?**

Comment: Not sure if that's the reason (worked with Django long time ago)... Try to change "super" part to ```super(MyForm, self).clean()``` also pick up cleaned_data from ```self.cleaned_data```

Comment: Also I would ```return self.cleaned_data``` at the end. As for get access to FileField - you should be fine (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055029/django-forms-filefield-validation).

Comment: @AlexanderB. I made the changes you suggested, but it still comes up empty. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was not the form, but the associated view:

**Wrong forms.py:**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        mytext = request.POST.get("mytext")
        myfile = request.FILES.get("myfile")
```

I didn't pass `request.FILES` to the form, so no wonder the validation didn't find it. While below this point, I retrieved the file directly from the request and was fine.

**Right forms.py:**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        mytext = form.cleaned_data.get("mytext")
        myfile = form.cleaned_data.get("myfile")
```